# Unable to add OR condition in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I want to add OR condition in Regex pattern. I have to two condition here is the example:-

```
Ext.Array.indexOf(value, "**(..") >= 0 || value.match(`/[\s\S]*\([A-Za-z]{1,}\)_\[[\s\S]*/`);
```

I just want to add this condition `**(..` in this pattern `/[\s\S]*\([A-Za-z]{1,}\)_\[[\s\S]*/`

Can any body help me on this?

Here is  my string

`On **(..SPECIFY DATE..) at **(..SPECIFY TOWNSHIP..), whilst upon the railway, without the written permission of the operator,  (A)_[displayed for the purpose of advertising or publicity **(..SPECIFY ITEMS..)]_ (B)_[distributed **(..SPECIFY ITEMS..)]_`

Comment: What does `**` mean?

Comment: `indexOf()` doesn't do regexp matching.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with a sample of inputs, expected output and a clear problem statement.

Comment: You can use `Ext.Array.find()` to search for an element that satisfies a condition function.

Comment: Your question is unclear and does not explain the goal. The regex you want to add does not make sense. Your question also lacks examples of what you tried, which should be accompanied by descriptions of how those attempts failed.

Comment: @CinCout it is the part of string. I mean to say that these are words from my string that need to match.
 String example:- 
On **(..SPECIFY DATE..) at **(..SPECIFY TOWNSHIP..), whilst upon the railway, without the written permission of the operator,  (A)_[displayed for the purpose of advertising or publicity **(..SPECIFY ITEMS..)]_ (B)_[distributed **(..SPECIFY ITEMS..)]_

Comment: So you are looking for two asterisks, followed by an opening brace and two dots? Are you aware that all of that has special meaning in regex?

Comment: You will have to *esacpe* the asterisks and the bracket and the dots

Comment: Is `Ext.Array` a string or an array of strings?

Comment: This is called an X/Y problem. What is the aim of the RegEx? What is the expected end result?

Comment: You add this by prepending it to the pattern: [`\*\*\(\.\.[\s\S]*\([A-Za-z]+\)_\[[\s\S]*`](https://regex101.com/r/scmPKw/1) now the pattern will start at `**(..` which is mandatory. This is different to your previous code where just either condition needs to be satisfied. It's a bit unclear.

Comment: @bobblebubble its not working but it works when I add | or condition /\*\*\(\.\.|[\s\S]*\([A-Za-z]{1,}\)_\[[\s\S]*/.Can you please guide me how we can use this without OR condtion?

Comment: @NectarMind Have you looked [at the demo](https://regex101.com/r/scmPKw/1). Play around with it. I don't understand your exact requirements :) Maybe make the quesiton more clear, provide further samples that should match and fail.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find()` to search for an array element that satisfies a predicate function.

```
var index = Ext.Array.find(value => value.match(/\*\*\(\.\.|[\s\S]*\([A-Za-z]{1,}\)_\[[\s\S]*/))
```

`|` can be used in the regexp to specify alternative patterns to match.

Comment: Barmar, as you mentioned OR condition \*\*\(\.\.| ,
Can we add this condition without OR condition. Means I want to add this \*\*\(\.\. condition without any OR condition?

Comment: Of course, if you only want to search for one thing you don't need OR.